# How to customize success screen after google marketplace app installation?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

Is there a way to specify what kind of success screen Google marketplace is showing after an App has been successfully added by a user?

The current success screen is misleading users, as it is pointing to opening an existing document that users do not have at this point. A screen showing how to create a new document would be much more helpful. Is there a way to specify this in the google developer console?
[Misleading success screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be9o5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible to change the message that will be shown when an AddOn is installed. It's automatic and it depends on the platform the AddOn is designed for.

### Workaround

You can provide additional information using the Setup URL field in the `Store Listing` from G Suite Marketplace API management menu.

In your Google Cloud Console select the project and then `APIs & Services > Library > G Suite Marketplace SDK > Manage`.

Providing this URL will activate second page in the post installation pop up. At this URL you can have a webpage with an AddOn walk-through for your users.

### Reference

[G Suite Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace)

Comment: Alessandro, you are saying it's automatic and it depends on the platform the AddOn is installed. Can you please elaborate on what is meant by the platform in this case? Isn't it google workspace in this case? 

We are seeing other apps alongside ours, which produce a different message. For example, for the app called Screencastify the message correctly informs about the fact that the app is to be found "under the Apps launcher icon". How do we achieve that?

Thanks a lot for your help!